# How do you start a program stored on a UNC share from the command line with parameters?

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, shortcut

There's an in-house program we use and it's stored on a UNC share so that updates are transparent.  I'd like to supply it some command line parameters like so:

```
\\server\share\in_house_thingy.exe myusername mypassword
```

But I can't seem to get it to work in either CMD or PowerShell or via a shortcut.

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Could you clarify what exactly you mean by "can't get it to work"? It doesn't start, it's unable to parse its command line, it runs over your dog, etc, etc? The current description is much too vague.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a shortcut, change the target to be like:

```
"\\server\share\in_house_thingy.exe" myusername mypassword
```

unless you really do want to have to use powershell to make this work.

Comment: That would work in PowerShell too.  There are added benefits to using the Process object.

Comment: You will want to begin that line with an Ampersand (&) to get Powershell to switch into command mode before it attempts to parse the quoted string. & "\\quoted\path\to execute.exe" For more on running non-Powershell commands in Powershell, see the gotcha posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/803521/powershell-pitfalls/7028380#7028380

Answer (score 7):

You could use:

```
$app = '\\server\share\in_house_thingy.exe'
$arguments = 'myusername mypassword'
$process = [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start($app, $arguments)
```

The $process object will give you a live process object if you want to get an exit code or  other information from that process.

Answer (score 1):

use `%~dp0` in a batch file for the current (unc) path including the trailing `\`

in a powershell script use this for the current (unc) path without trailing `\`

```
$0 = $myInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
$dp0 = [System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed that there's a .CMD file that's copying the file from the share to the temp directory and running it locally.

If y'all could just vote this answer up if there's no better solution, that'll work.

Comment: this is no answer but a workaround. That's why nobody up voted this answer I guess.  I would suggest accepting the other example which does show how to invoke an application on a UNC path.