# Powershell pitfalls

Tags: powershell

What Powershell pitfalls you have fall into? :-)

Mine are:

```
# -----------------------------------
function foo()
{
    @("text")
}

# Expected 1, actually 4.
(foo).length

# -----------------------------------
if(@($null, $null))
{
    Write-Host "Expected to be here, and I am here."
}

if(@($null))
{
    Write-Host "Expected to be here, BUT NEVER EVER."
}

# -----------------------------------

function foo($a)
{
    # I thought this is right.
    #if($a -eq $null)
    #{
    #    throw "You can't pass $null as argument."
    #}

    # But actually it should be:
    if($null -eq $a)
    {
        throw "You can't pass $null as argument."
    }
}

foo @($null, $null)

# -----------------------------------

# There is try/catch, but no callstack reported.
function foo() 
{
   bar
}

function bar() 
{
  throw "test"
}

# Expected:
#  At bar() line:XX
#  At foo() line:XX
#  
# Actually some like this:
#  At bar() line:XX
foo
```

Would like to know yours to walk them around :-)

Comment: You should probably make this a community WIKI since it's a poll

Comment: I second that recommendation.

Comment: Edit it. At the lower right hand side (I think it is there) there will be a check box and it will say Community Wiki next to it.

Answer (score 14):

My personal favorite is

```
function foo() {
  param ( $param1, $param2 = $(throw "Need a second parameter"))
  ...
}

foo (1,2)
```

For those unfamiliar with powershell that line throws because instead of passing 2 parameters it actually creates an array and passes one parameter.  You have to call it as follows

```
foo 1 2
```

Comment: This brings back memories of how VB & VBScript handle parentheses around arguments.  I can't find a handy reference but something like call func x,y,z and call func(x,y,z) were different

Comment: Call essentially ignores any return value and forces the use of (). Without call subs must not use () and functions must use ().

Answer (score 11):

Another fun one.  Not handling an expression by default writes it to the pipeline.  Really annoying when you don't realize a particular function returns a value.

```
function example() {
  param ( $p1 ) {
  if ( $p1 ) {
    42
  }
  "done"
}

PS> example $true 
42
"done"
```

Answer (score 10):

```
$files = Get-ChildItem . -inc *.extdoesntexist
foreach ($file in $files) {
    "$($file.Fullname.substring(2))"
}
```

Fails with:

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:3 char:25
+ $file.Fullname.substring <<<< (2)
```

Fix it like so:

```
$files = @(Get-ChildItem . -inc *.extdoesntexist)
foreach ($file in $files) {
    "$($file.Fullname.substring(2))"
}
```

Bottom line is that the foreach statement will loop on a scalar value even if that scalar value is $null.  When Get-ChildItem in the first example returns nothing, $files gets assinged $null.  If you are expecting an array of items to be returned by a command but there is a chance it will only return 1 item or zero items, put @() around the command.  Then you will always get an array - be it of 0, 1 or N items.  Note: If the item is already an array putting `@()` has no effect - it will still be the very same array (i.e. there is no extra array wrapper).

Comment: Very interesting, thank you! I have updated my response inspired by your answer.

Comment: As of PowerShell V3, foreach no longer iterates over just $null. That is, `foreach( $d in $null ) { "This never displays!" }` does as it says. Yay! However, Keith's comment regarding forcing your results into an array is very much current, and is a good pattern to practice.

Answer (score 9):

### PowerShell Gotchas

There are a few pitfall that repeatedly reappear on StackOverflow. It is recommend to do some research if you are not familiar with these PowerShell gotchas before [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a new question. It might even be a good idea to investigate in these PowerShell gotchas before [answering](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) a PowerShell question to make sure that you teach the questioner the right thing.

*TLDR:* In **PowerShell**:

1. the comparison equality operator is: `-eq`
   <sup>(Stackoverflow example: [**Powershell simple syntax if condition not working**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42250254/1701026))</sup>
2. parentheses and commas are **not** used with arguments
   <sup>(Stackoverflow example: [**How do I pass multiple parameters into a function in PowerShell?**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4988226/1701026))</sup>
3. output properties are based on the first object in the pipeline
   <sup>(Stackoverflow example: [**Not all properties displayed**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44428189/1701026))</sup>
4. the pipeline unrolls
   <sup>(Stackoverflow example: [**Pipe complete array-objects instead of array items one at a time?**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29973212/1701026))</sup>
   a. single item collections
   <sup>(Stackoverflow example: [**Powershell ArrayList turns a single array item back into a string**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47341167/1701026))</sup>
   b. embedded arrays
   <sup>(Stackoverflow example: [**Return Multidimensional Array From Function**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40220590/1701026))</sup>
   c. output collections
   <sup>(Stackoverflow example: [**Why does PowerShell flatten arrays automatically?**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57023626/1701026))</sup>
5. `$Null` should be on the left side of the equality comparison operator
   <sup>(Stackoverflow example: [**Should $null be on the left side of the equality comparison**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58217913/1701026))</sup>
6. parentheses and assignments choke the pipeline
   <sup>(Stackoverflow example: [**Importing 16MB CSV Into Variable Creates >600MB's Memory Usage**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60353691/1701026))</sup>
7. the increase assignment operator (`+=`) might become expensive
   <sup>Stackoverflow example: [**Improve the efficiency of my PowerShell scrip**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53110553/1701026)</sup>
8. The `Get-Content` cmdlet returns separate lines
   <sup>Stackoverflow example: [**Multiline regex to match config block**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12572164/17010266)</sup>

## Examples and explanations

Some of the gotchas might really feel counter-intuitive but often can be explained by some very nice PowerShell features along with the [pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines), [expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing#expression-mode)/[argument mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing#argument-mode) and [type casting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion).

### 1. The comparison equality operator is: `-eq`

Unlike the Microsoft scripting language [VBScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VBScript) and some other programming languages, the [comparison equality operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.1#equality-operators) differs from the [assignment operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_assignment_operators) (**`=`**) and is:  **`-eq`**.

*Note:* assigning a value to a variable might pass through the value if needed:

```
$a = $b = 3   # The value 3 is assigned to both variables $a and $b.
```

This implies that following statement might be unexpectedly [truthy or falsy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39983695/1701026):

```
If ($a = $b) {
    # (assigns $b to $a and) returns a truthy if $b is e.g. 3
} else {
    # (assigns $b to $a and) returns a falsy if $b is e.g. 0
}
```

### 2. Parentheses and commas are **not** used with arguments

Unlike a lot of other programming languages and the way a primitive PowerShell function is defined, calling a function doesn't require parentheses or commas for their related arguments. Use **spaces** to separate the parameter arguments:

```
MyFunction($Param1, $Param2 $Param3) {
    # ...
}

MyFunction 'one' 'two' 'three' # assigns 'one' to $Param1, 'two' to $Param2, 'three' to $Param3
```

- Parentheses and commas are used for calling ([.Net](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/learn/dotnet/what-is-dotnet)) methods.
- Commas are used to define arrays. `MyFunction 'one', 'two', 'three'` (or `MyFunction('one', 'two', 'three')`) will load the array `@('one', 'two', 'three')` into the first parameter (`$Param1`).
- Parentheses will intepret the containing contents as a single collection into memory (and choke the PowerShell pipeline) and should only be used as such, e.g. to call an embedded function, e.g.:

```
MyFunction (MyOtherFunction) # passes the results MyOtherFunction to the first positional parameter of MyFunction ($Param1)
MyFunction One $Two (getThree) # assigns 'One' to $Param1, $Two to $Param2, the results of getThree to $Param3
```

*Note:* that quoting text arguments (as the word `one` in the later example) is only required when it contains spaces or special characters.

### 3. Output properties are based on the first object in the pipeline

In a PowerShell pipeline each object is processed and passed on by a [cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com//powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/cmdlet-overview)  (that is [implemented for the middle of a pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/strongly-encouraged-development-guidelines#support-well-defined-pipeline-input-sc02)) similar to how objects are processed and passed on by workstations in an assembly line. Meaning each cmdlet processes one item at the time while the prior cmdlet (workstation) simultaneously processes the upcoming one. This way, the objects aren't loaded into memory at once (less memory usage) and could already be processed before the next one is supplied (or even exists). The disadvantage of this feature is that there is no oversight of what ([or how many](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67534378/1701026)) objects are expected to follow.
Therefore most PowerShell cmdlets assume that all the objects in the pipeline correspond to the first one and have the same properties which is usually the case, *but not always...*

```
$List =
    [pscustomobject]@{ one = 'a1'; two = 'a2' },
    [pscustomobject]@{ one = 'b1'; two = 'b2'; three = 'b3' }

$List |Select-Object *
one two
--- ---
a1  a2
b1  b2
```

As you see, the third column `three` is missing from the results as it didn't exists in the first object and the PowerShell was already outputting the results prior it was aware of the exists of the second object.
On way to workaround this behavior is to explicitly define the properties (of all the following objects) at forehand:

```
$List |Select-Object one, two, three

one two three
--- --- -----
a1  a2
b1  b2  b3
```

See also proposal: [`#13906` Add -UnifyProperties parameter to Select-Object](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13906)

### 4. The pipeline unrolls

This feature might come in handy if it complies with the straightforward expectation:

```
$Array = 'one', 'two', 'three'
$Array.Length
3
```

#### a. single item collections

But it might get confusing:

```
$Selection = $Array |Select-Object -First 2
$Selection.Length
2
$Selection[0]
one
```

when the collection is down to a single item:

```
$Selection = $Array |Select-Object -First 1
$Selection.Length
3
$Selection[0]
o
```

**Explanation**
When the pipeline outputs a single item which is assigned to a variable, it is *not* assigned as a collection (with 1 item, like: <strike>`@('one')`</strike>) but as a scalar item (the item itself, like: `'one'`).
Which means that the property `.Length` (which is in fact an alias for the property `.Count` for an array) is no longer applied on the array but on the string: `'one'.length` which equals `3`. And in case of the index `$Selection[0]` , the first character of the string `'one'[0]` (which equals the character `o`) is returned .

**Workaround**
To workaround this behavior, you might force the scalar item to an array using the [Array subexpression operator  `@( )`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators#array-subexpression-operator--):

```
$Selection = $Array |Select-Object -First 1
@($Selection).Length
1
@($Selection)[0]
one
```

Knowing that in the case the `$Selection` is already an array, it will will not be further increased in depth (<strike>@(@('one', 'two'))</strike>, see the next section **4b. Embedded collections are flattened**).

#### b. embedded arrays

When an array (or a collection) includes embedded arrays, like:

```
$Array = @(@('a', 'b'), @('c', 'd'))
$Array.Count
2
```

All the embedded items will be processed in the pipeline and consequently returns a flat array when *displayed* or assigned to a new variable:

```
$Processed = $Array |ForEach-Object { $_ }
$Processed.Count
4
$Processed
a
b
c
d
```

To iterate the embedded arrays, you might use the [`foreach` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_foreach):

```
foreach ($Item in $Array) { $Item.Count }
2
2
```

Or a simply [`for`  loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_for):

```
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $Array.Count; $i++) { $Array[$i].Count }
2
2
```

#### c. output collections

Collections are usually unrolled when they are placed on the pipeline:

```
function GetList {
   [Collections.Generic.List[String]]@('a', 'b')
}
(GetList).GetType().Name
Object[]
```

To output the collection as a single item, use the [comma operator  `,`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators#comma-operator-):

```
function GetList {
   ,[Collections.Generic.List[String]]@('a', 'b')
}
(GetList).GetType().Name
List`1
```

### 5. `$Null` should be on the left side of the equality comparison operator

This gotcha is related to this [comparison operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators) feature:

> [When the input of an operator is a scalar value, the operator returns a **Boolean** value. When the input is a collection, the operator returns the elements of the collection that match the right-hand value of the expression. If there are no matches in the collection, comparison operators return an empty array.](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.1#common-features)

This means for scalars:

```
'a'   -eq 'a'   # returns $True
'a'   -eq 'b'   # returns $False
'a'   -eq $Null # returns $False
$Null -eq $Null # returns $True
```

and for collections, the matching elements are returned which evaluates to either a [truthy or falsy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39983695/1701026) condition:

```
'a',   'b',   'c'   -eq 'a'   # returns 'a' (truthy)
'a',   'b',   'c'   -eq 'd'   # returns an empty array (falsy)
'a',   'b',   'c'   -eq $Null # returns an empty array (falsy)
'a',   $Null, 'c'   -eq $Null # returns $Null (falsy)
'a',   $Null, $Null -eq $Null # returns @($Null, $Null) (truthy!!!)
$Null, $Null, $Null -eq $Null # returns @($Null, $Null, $Null) (truthy!!!)
```

In other words, to check whether a variable is `$Null` (and exclude a collection containing multiple `$Null`s), **put `$Null` at the LHS (left hand side) of the equality comparison operator**:

```
if ($Null -eq $MyVariable) { ...
```

### 6. Parentheses and assignments choke the pipeline

The [PowerShell Pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines) is not *just* a series of commands connected by pipeline operators (`|`) (ASCII 124). It is a concept to simultaneously *stream* individual objects through a sequence of [cmdlets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/cmdlet-overview). If a cmdlet (or function) is written according to the [Strongly Encouraged Development Guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/strongly-encouraged-development-guidelines) and [implemented for the middle of a pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/strongly-encouraged-development-guidelines#implement-for-the-middle-of-a-pipeline), it takes each single object from the pipeline, processes it and passes the results to the next cmdlet just before it takes and processes the next object in the pipeline. Meaning that for a simple pipeline as:

```
Import-Csv .\Input.csv |Select-Object -Property Column1, Column2 |Export-Csv .\Output.csv
```

As the last cmdlet writes an object to the `.\Output.csv` file, the `Select-Object` cmdlet selects the properties of the next object and the `Import-Csv` reads the next object from the `.\input.csv` file (see also: [Pipeline in Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68254012/1701026)). This will keep the memory usage low (especially where there are lots of object/records to process) and therefore might result in a faster throughput. To facilitate the pipeline, the PowerShell objects are quiet fat as each individual object contains all the property information (along with e.g. the property name).
Therefore it is not a good practice to choke the pipeline for no reason. There are two senarios that choke the pipeline:

1. **Parentheses**, e.g.:

```
(Import-Csv .\Input.csv) |Select-Object -Property Column1, Column2 |Export-Csv .\Output.csv
```

Where all the `.\Input.csv` records are loaded as an array of PowerShell objects into memory before passing it on to the `Select-Object` cmdlet.

2. **Assignments**, e.g.:

```
$Objects = Import-Csv .\Input.csv
$Objects |Select-Object -Property Column1, Column2 |Export-Csv .\Output.csv
```

Where all the `.\Input.csv` records are loaded as an array of PowerShell objects into `$Objects` (memory as well) before passing it on to the `Select-Object` cmdlet.

### 7. the increase assignment operator (`+=`) might become expensive

The [increase assignment operator (`+=`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_assignment_operators#the-assignment-by-addition-operator) is [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) to increase and assign [primitives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_primitive) as .e.g. `$a += $b` where `$a` is assigned `$b + 1`.  The increase assignment operator can also be used for adding new items to a collection (or to `String` types and `hash tables`) but might get pretty [expensive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9888431/1701026) as the costs increases with each iteration (the size of the collection). The reason for this is that objects as array collections are immutable and the right variable in not just appended but **appended *and reassigned** to the left variable. For details see also: [avoid using the increase assignment operator (`+=`) to create a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60708578/1701026)

### 8. The `Get-Content` cmdlet returns separate lines

There are probably quite some more *cmdlet* gotchas, knowing that there exist a lot of (internal and external) cmdlets. In contrast to engine related gotchas, these gotchas are often easier to highlight (with e.g. a warning) as happend with [`ConvertTo-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/epowershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json) (see: [Unexpected ConvertTo-Json results? Answer: it has a default -Depth of 2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53583677/1701026)) or "fix".  But there is very clasic gotcha in [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) which tight into the PowerShell general concept of streaming objects (in this case lines) rather than passing everything (the whole contents of the file) in once:

```
Get-Content .\Input.txt -Match '\r?\n.*Test.*\r?\n'
```

Will never work because, by default, `Get-Contents` returns a stream of objects where each object contains a single string (a line without any line breaks).

```
(Get-Content .\Input.txt).GetType().Name
Object[]
(Get-Content .\Input.txt)[0].GetType().Name
String
```

In fact:

```
Get-Content .\Input.txt -Match 'Test'
```

Returns all the lines with the word `Test` in it as `Get-Contents` puts every single line on the pipeline and [when the input is a collection, the operator returns the elements of the collection that match the right-hand value of the expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators#common-features).

*Note:* since PowerShell version 3, `Get-Contents` has a `-Raw` parameter that reads all the content of the concerned file at once, Meaning that this: `Get-Content -Raw .\Input.txt -Match '\r?\n.*Test.*\r?\n'` will work as it loads the whole file into memory.

Answer (score 8):

```
# The pipeline doesn't enumerate hashtables.
$ht = @{"foo" = 1; "bar" = 2}
$ht | measure

# Workaround: call GetEnumerator
$ht.GetEnumerator() | measure
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is something Ive stumble upon lately (PowerShell 2.0 CTP):

```
$items = "item0", "item1", "item2"

$part = ($items | select-string "item0")

$items = ($items | where {$part -notcontains $_})
```

what do you think that $items be at the end of the script?

I was expecting "item1", "item2" but instead the value of $items is: "item0", "item1", "item2".

Comment: You aren't changing the value of items after you first set it.  So I would be surprised if it changed.  :)

Comment: I change the snippet so that it would make sense.

Comment: In that case, what is wrong is that $part contains a MatchInfo object.  Since the MatchInfo object doesn't contain anything, the last comparison always returns true.

Answer (score 3):

Say you've got the following XML file:

```
<Root>
    <Child />
    <Child />
</Root>
```

Run this:

```
PS > $myDoc = [xml](Get-Content $pathToMyDoc)
PS > @($myDoc.SelectNodes("/Root/Child")).Count
2
PS > @($myDoc.Root.Child).Count
2
```

Now edit the XML file so it has no Child nodes, just the Root node, and run those statements again:

```
PS > $myDoc = [xml](Get-Content $pathToMyDoc)
PS > @($myDoc.SelectNodes("/Root/Child")).Count
0
PS > @($myDoc.Root.Child).Count
1
```

That 1 is annoying when you want to iterate over a collection of nodes using foreach if and only if there actually are any. This is how I learned that you cannot use the XML handler's property (dot) notation as a simple shortcut. I believe what's happening is that SelectNodes returns a collection of 0. When @'ed, it is transformed from an XPathNodeList to an Object[] (check GetType()), but the length is preserved. The dynamically generated $myDoc.Root.Child property (which essentially does not exist) returns $null. When $null is @'ed, it becomes an array of length 1.

Answer (score 3):

There are some tricks to building command lines for utilities that were not built with Powershell in mind:

- To run an executable who's name starts with a number, preface it with an Ampersand (&).

`& 7zip.exe`

- To run an executable with a space anywhere in the path, preface it with an Ampersand (&) and wrap it in quotes, as you would any string. This means that strings in a variable can be executed as well.

`# Executing a string with a space.
& 'c:\path with spaces\command with spaces.exe'`

`# Executing a string with a space, after first saving it in a variable.
$a = 'c:\path with spaces\command with spaces.exe'
& $a`

- Parameters and arguments are passed to legacy utilities positionally. So it is important to quote them the way the utility expects to see them. In general, one would quote when it contains spaces or does not start with a letter, number or dash (-).

`C:\Path\utility.exe '/parameter1' 'Value #1' 1234567890`

- Variables can be used to pass string values containing spaces or special characters.

`$b = 'string with spaces and special characters (-/&)'
utility.exe $b`

- Alternatively array expansion can be used to pass values as well.

`$c = @('Value #1', $Value2)
utility.exe $c`

- If you want Powershell to wait for an application to complete, you have to consume the output, either by piping the output to something or using Start-Process.

`# Saving output as a string to a variable.
$output = ping.exe example.com | Out-String`

`# Piping the output.
ping stackoverflow.com | where { $_ -match '^reply' }`

`# Using Start-Process affords the most control.
Start-Process -Wait SomeExecutable.com`

- Because of the way they display their output, some command line utilities will appear to hang when ran inside of Powershell_ISE.exe, particularly when awaiting input from the user. These utilities will usually work fine when ran within Powershell.exe console.

Answer (score 3):

### On Functions...

- The subtleties of processing pipeline input in a function with respect to using  `$_` or `$input` and with respect to the `begin`, `process`, and `end` blocks.
- How to handle the six principal equivalence classes of input delivered to a function (no input, null, empty string, scalar, list, list with null and/or empty) -- for both **direct** input and **pipeline** input -- *and get what you expect*.
- The correct calling syntax for sending multiple arguments to a function.

I discuss these points and more at length in my Simple-Talk.com article [Down the Rabbit Hole- A Study in PowerShell Pipelines, Functions, and Parameters](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-tools/down-the-rabbit-hole--a-study-in-powershell-pipelines,-functions,-and-parameters/) and also provide an accompanying [wallchart](http://www.simple-talk.com/content/file.ashx?file=5771)--here is a glimpse showing the various calling syntax pitfalls for a function taking 3 arguments:
[image: function syntax pitfalls]

---

### On Modules...

These points are expounded upon in my Simple-Talk.com article [Further Down the Rabbit Hole: PowerShell Modules and Encapsulation](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-tools/further-down-the-rabbit-hole-powershell-modules-and-encapsulation/).

- Dot-sourcing a file inside a script using a relative path is relative to your current directory -- **not** the directory where the script resides!
  To be relative to the script use this function to locate your script directory: *[Update for PowerShell V3+: Just use the builtin `$PSScriptRoot` variable!]*

  ```
  function Get-ScriptDirectory
  { Split-Path $script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path }
  ```
- Modules must be stored as `...Modules\name\name.psm1` or `...\Modules\any_subpath\name\name.psm1`. That is, you cannot just use `...Modules\name.psm1` -- the name of the immediate parent of the module must match the base name of the module. This chart shows the various failure modes when this rule is violated:

[image: module naming requirements]

---

### 2015.06.25 A Pitfall Reference Chart

Simple-Talk.com just published the last of my triumvirate of in-depth articles on PowerShell pitfalls. The first two parts are in the form of a quiz that helps you appreciate a select group of pitfalls; the last part is a wallchart (albeit it would need a rather high-ceilinged room) containing 36 of the most common pitfalls (some adapted from answers on this page), giving concrete examples and workarounds for most. Read more [here](http://www.simple-talk.com/sysadmin/powershell/the-poster-of-the-plethora-of-powershell-pitfalls/).

Comment: Actually, I use \modules\name.psm1.  I have to include the extension (import-module name.psm1) but that keeps most of my personal modules in the same folder rather than in dozens of separate sub-folders.

Answer (score 2):

alex2k8, I think this example of yours is good to talk about:

```
# -----------------------------------
function foo($a){
    # I thought this is right.
    #if($a -eq $null)
    #{
    #    throw "You can't pass $null as argument."
    #}
    # But actually it should be:
    if($null -eq $a)
    {
        throw "You can't pass $null as argument." 
    }
}
foo @($null, $null)
```

PowerShell can use some of the comparators against arrays like this:

```
$array -eq $value
## Returns all values in $array that equal $value
```

With that in mind, the original example returns two items (the two $null values in the array), which evalutates to $true because you end up with a collection of more than one item.  Reversing the order of the arguments stops the array comparison.

This functionality is very handy in certain situations, but it is something you need to be aware of (just like array handling in PowerShell).

Answer (score 2):

Functions 'foo' and 'bar' looks equivalent.

```
function foo() { $null  }
function bar() { }
```

E.g.

```
(foo) -eq $null
# True

(bar) -eq $null
# True
```

But:

```
foo | %{ "foo" }
# Prints: foo

bar | %{ "bar" }
# PRINTS NOTHING
```

Returning $null and returning nothing is not equivalent dealing with pipes.

---

This one is inspired by **Keith Hill** example...

```
function bar() {}

$list = @(foo)
$list.length
# Prints: 0

# Now let's try the same but with a temporal variable.
$tmp = foo
$list = @($tmp)
$list.length
# Prints: 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Another one:

```
$x = 2
$y = 3
$a,$b = $x,$y*5
```

because of operators precedence there is not 25 in $b; the command is the same as ($x,$y)*5
the correct version is

```
$a,$b = $x,($y*5)
```

Answer (score 2):

The logical and bitwise operators don't follow standard precedence rules.  The operator -and should have a higher priority than -or yet they're evaluated strictly left-to-right.

For example, compare logical operators between PowerShell and Python (or virtually any other modern language):

```
# PowerShell
PS> $true -or $false -and $false
False

# Python
>>> True or False and False
True
```

...and bitwise operators:

```
# PowerShell
PS> 1 -bor 0 -band 0
0

# Python
>>> 1 | 0 & 0
1
```

Answer (score 1):

Another one I ran into recently: [string] parameters that accept pipeline input are not strongly typed in practice.  You can pipe anything at all and PS will coerce it via ToString().

```
function Foo 
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [parameter(Mandatory=$True, ValueFromPipeline=$True)]
        [string] $param
    )

    process { $param }
}

get-process svchost | Foo
```

Unfortunately there is no way to turn this off.  Best workaround I could think of:

```
function Bar
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [parameter(Mandatory=$True, ValueFromPipeline=$True)]
        [object] $param
    )

    process 
    { 
        if ($param -isnot [string]) {
            throw "Pass a string you fool!"
        }
        # rest of function goes here
    }
}
```

edit - a better workaround I've started using...

Add this to your custom type XML -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Types>
  <Type>
    <Name>System.String</Name>
    <Members>
      <ScriptProperty>
        <Name>StringValue</Name>
        <GetScriptBlock>
          $this
        </GetScriptBlock>
      </ScriptProperty>
    </Members>
  </Type>
</Types>
```

Then write functions like this:

```
function Bar
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [parameter(Mandatory=$True, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$True)]
        [Alias("StringValue")]
        [string] $param
    )

    process 
    { 
        # rest of function goes here
    }
}
```

Comment: PowerShell will automatically do any coversion it needs to that is available.  You can see this with DateTime as well.

Answer (score 0):

This works.  But almost certainly not in the way you think it's working.

```
PS> $a = 42;
PS> [scriptblock]$b = { $a }
PS> & $b
42
```

Answer (score 0):

This one has tripped me up before, using $o.SomeProperty where it should be $($o.SomeProperty).

Comment: This is only and always the case within quoted strings.

Comment: And double-quoted strings at that since single quoted strings and here strings don't support variable expansion, sub-expressions or escape chars.

Answer (score 0):

```
# $x is not defined
[70]: $x -lt 0
True
[71]: [int]$x -eq 0
True
```

So, what's $x..?

Comment: Two different comparisons, the first is $null to 0, which appears to be less than 1.  The second is comparing 0 to 0.  Interestingly, $null is less than 0, but greater than any negative number.

Comment: I know, that was the weird behaviour I wanted to point out. $x is less than 0 and equal to 0 at the same time.

Comment: $x is $null since it is undefined, which means $x is all values when you do an inequality comparison it will always be true.  When you force null to an int value it will be 0.

Comment: I'm used to null (in db contexts) always forcing boolean results to false, rather than true.  I'm surprised at this result in PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

Forgetting that $_ gets overwritten in blocks made me scratch my head in confusion a couple times, and similarly for multiple reg-ex matches and the $matches array. >.<

Answer (score 0):

Remembering to explicitly type pscustom objects from imported data tables as numeric  so they can  be sorted correctly:

```
$CVAP_WA=foreach ($i in $C){[PSCustomObject]@{ `
                County=$i.county; `
                TotalVote=[INT]$i.TotalBallots; `
                RegVoters=[INT]$i.regvoters; `
                Turnout_PCT=($i.TotalBallots/$i.regvoters)*100; `
                CVAP=[INT]($B | ? {$_.GeoName -match $i.county}).CVAP_EST }}
```

PS C:\Politics> $CVAP_WA | sort -desc TotalVote |ft -auto -wrap

```
County       TotalVote RegVoters Turnout_PCT    CVAP CVAP_TV_PCT CVAP_RV_PCT
------       --------- --------- -----------    ---- ----------- -----------
King            973088   1170638      83.189 1299290      74.893      90.099
Pierce          349377    442985       78.86  554975      62.959      79.837
Snohomish       334354    415504      80.461  478440      69.832       86.81
Spokane         227007    282442      80.346  342060      66.398      82.555
Clark           193102    243155      79.453  284190      67.911       85.52
```

Answer (score 0):

Mine are both related to file copying...

**Square Brackets in File Names**
I once had to move a very large/complicated folder structure using `Move-Item -Path C:\Source -Destination C:\Dest`. At the end of the process there were still a number of files in source directory. I noticed that every remaining file had square brackets in the name.

The problem was that the `-Path` parameter treats square brackets as wildcards. 
EG. If you wanted to copy Log001 to Log200, you could use square brackets as follows:
`Move-Item -Path C:\Source\Log[001-200].log`.

In my case, to avoid square brackets being interpreted as wildcards, I should have used the `-LiteralPath` parameter.

**ErrorActionPreference**
The `$ErrorActionPreference` variable is ignored when using `Move-Item` and `Copy-Item` with the `-Verbose` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

**Treating the ExitCode of a Process as a Boolean.**

eg, with this code:

```
$p = Start-Process foo.exe -NoNewWindow -Wait -PassThru
if ($p.ExitCode) {
  # handle error
}
```

things are good, unless say foo.exe doesn't exist or otherwise fails to launch.
in that case `$p` will be `$null`, and `[bool]($null.ExitCode)` is False.

a simple fix is to replace the logic with `if ($p.ExitCode -ne 0) {}`,
however for clarity of code imo the following is better: `if (($p -eq $null) -or ($p.ExitCode -ne 0)) {}`