# Reading in multiple lines with regex?

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a file that looks like this:

```
SPECIMEN: Procedure: xxxx1 A) Location: yyyy2
Major zzz B) Location: something
text here C) more


CLINICAL DIAGNOSIS: xyz
```

Where the newlines are `CR` then `LF`.

I'm trying to make regex that reads from the end of `Procedure:` until the start of `CLINICAL DIAGNOSIS` but having issues reading multiple lines.

Here's what I have:

```
$input_file = 'c:\Path\0240188.txt'
$regex = ‘(?m)^SPECIMEN: Procedure: (.*)CLINICAL DIAGNOSIS:’
select-string -Path $input_file -Pattern $regex -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value }
```

Which doesn't return anything.

If I change the line to:

```
$regex = ‘(?m)^SPECIMEN: Procedure: (.*)’
```

It grabs the first line, but not the rest. I assumed `(?m)` was suppose to grab multiple lines for me.

Any tips?

Comment: Any way to _slurp_ that whole file into a variable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$regex = '(?ms).*SPECIMEN: Procedure:(.+)CLINICAL DIAGNOSIS: '

Get-Content $input_file -Delimiter 'CLINICAL DIAGNOSIS: '|
 foreach {@($_) -match 'CLINICAL DIAGNOSIS: ' -replace $regex,'$1'}
```

Using 'Clinical Diagnosis' as a delimiter eliminates the need to read in all the data at once and resolve/capture multiple matches at once.

Answer (score 1):

`(?m)` causes `^` and `$` anchors to match the beginning and end of each line when implemented. You want to use the inline `(?s)` modifier which forces the dot to match all characters, including line breaks.

```
$regex = ‘(?s)SPECIMEN: Procedure: (.*)CLINICAL DIAGNOSIS:’
```

Comment: This didn't give me any results. If I took out the `CLINICAL DIAGNOSIS:` in your line, it only ended up returning `SPECIMEN: Procedure: `; the `?` seems to be part of the issue causing this?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the $input_file only reads line by line, which doesn't help you here,

Try:

```
$fileContent = [io.file]::ReadAllText("C:\file.txt")
```

Or

```
$fileContent = Get-Content c:\file.txt -Raw
```

Taken from another post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12572164/multiline-regex-to-match-config-block).

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
$input_file = gc 'c:\Path\0240188.txt' | out-string
# or: gc c:\path\xxxxx.txt -raw  #with v3+
$regex = ‘(?s)\bSPECIMEN: Procedure: (.*?)CLINICAL DIAGNOSIS:’
$input_file | select-string -Pattern $regex -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches }
# or: [regex]::matches($input_file, $regex) # much faster
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a little regex trick like this:

```
Procedure:([\S\s]+)CLINICAL DIAGNOSIS
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/dP5yX8/1)**

[image]

Since the `.` matches everything except new lines you could use `[\S\s]+` to match everything as the image shows in green and also captures it using capturing group `(...)`. This trick works if you want to avoid using single line flag.