# Multiline regex match in PowerShell

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm trying to extract a certain block of lines from a text file, which contains something like this:

```
...
sCountry = "USA"
sCity = "New York"
sState = "New York"
...
sCountry = "USA"
sCity = "Los Angeles"
sState = "California"
```

where those three lines repeat throughout the text file; I just want to extract those lines of text, and put the data fields into a csv, so that I have something like

```
"USA","New York","New York"
"USA","Los Angeles","California"
...
```

So far I have this:

```
$inputPath = 'C:\folder\file.vbs'
$outputFile = 'C:\folder\extracted_data.csv'
$fileContent = [io.file]::ReadAllText($inputPath)

$regex = '(?sm)(s[A-Z][a-z]+ = "\w*"(\s*$)){3}'

$fileContent = $fileContent | Select-String $regex -AllMatches | % {$_.Matches} | % {$_.Value}
$fileContent = [regex]::Replace($fileContent, 'sCountry = ', '')
$fileContent = [regex]::Replace($fileContent, '(?sm)((^\s*)s[A-Z][a-z]+ = )', ',')
$fileContent > $outputFile
```

which I was able to obtain by looking at this:

[Multiline regex to match config block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12572164/multiline-regex-to-match-config-block).

However, my output file is empty when I run the script. It won't pattern-match with the `$regex` pattern I provided, but it WILL match on a single line if I do something like:

```
$regex = '(?sm)(sCountry = "\w*"(\s*$))'
```

but not if I do something like:

```
$regex = '(?sm)(s[A-Z][a-z]+ = "\w*"(\s*$))'
```

How do I make the pattern matching work across multiple lines?

Comment: What version of powershell are you using?

Comment: @mjolinor, Windows PowerShell ISE, 3.0, NOT (x86)

Answer (score 1):

Using you test data *exactly* as you have it in your post I took a different approach using `Select-String` and `ConvertFrom-StringData`. This has a minor flaw that could be overlooked (or addressed if you really need to). The caveat here is that the sCountry line has to occur first and the sState line has to occur last in the group.

```psh
$results = ((Get-Content C:\temp\test.txt -Raw) | 
    Select-String -Pattern "(?sm)sCountry.*?sState.*?$" -AllMatches).Matches.Value
$results | ForEach-Object{
    New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property ($_.Replace('"','') | ConvertFrom-StringData)
} | Export-CSV -NoTypeInformation C:\temp\output.csv
```

To get the data groups the regex here will grab everything from "sCountry" to then end of a line of the where the next "sState" occurs. This current logic would fail if there were other lines in between those besides the ones expected.  We get rid of the variable quotes with simple `.Replace('"','')`. I think it is minor but the resulting headers have leading s's which is probably not a big deal.

The object in PowerShell looks like this before it is exported to CSV

```
sCity       sCountry sState    
-----       -------- ------    
New York    USA      New York  
Los Angeles USA      California
```

Which will net output like this in a csv

```
"sCity","sCountry","sState"
"New York","USA","New York"
"Los Angeles","USA","California"
```

The cool think is not you could sort the data before you exported it. Or anything really that you could do with PowerShell objects.