# Exclude HTML comment from text file

Tags: powershell, html

I have a config file from which I need to output some text and convert it to a CSV. I am stuck at the first step which is that this file has few HTML comments which are to be excluded and the remaining text is to be used for exporting to CSV purposes.

HTML comment looks like following:

```
<!--<add name=                                />
    <add name=                                />
    <add name=                                />-->
```

I have tried different regex's to solve this, but no luck. The closest I have got is to exclude the first and third line using the below regex, but that doesn't solve the issue as second line is still present:

```
Get-Content –Path C:\Pathtothefile -notmatch "^\s*(<!--)|>*(-->)$"
```

This regex will take out the line which starts with , but not the middle one which is part of the comment. I have multiple files with multiple comments.

Tried several different combos `("<!--[^>]*(-->)$")`, no luck so far.

Answer (score 2):

In the documents you need to process the `<!--` always be at the start of the line and the `-->` at the end?  If so then you probably need to get the content, and run it through a loop where you process your document line by line, toggling a state variable for content, or not.

```
$data=@"
<!--<add name=                                />
    <add name=                                />
    <add name=                                />-->
a,b,c,d
1,2,3,4
"@
$state='content'
$data  -split "`n" |
ForEach-Object {
  If ($_ -match '^<!--') {
    $state='comment'
    return $null  # because `continue` doesn't work in a foreach-object
  }
  If ($_ -match '-->$') {
    $state='content'
    return $null
  }
  If ($state -eq 'content') {
    $_
  }
}
```

Results

```
a,b,c,d
1,2,3,4
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your response. Tried, but no luck:

$data= Get-Content C:\file.conf
$state='content'
$data  -split "`n" |
ForEach-Object {
  If ($_ -match '^<!--') {
    $state='comment'
    return $null
  }
  If ($_ -match '-->$') {
    $state='content'
    return $null
  }
  If ($state -eq 'content') {
    $_
  }
}

Comment: What happens when you try with your actual content?  Do you get errors, is the  comments included in the output, or something else?  My answer was mostly an example of the idea though, not meant to be a finished product.  You almost certainly will need to tweak things.

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing the content of your config file and despite [jscott's](https://serverfault.com/users/23067/jscott) hint.

- To have a RegEx match over several lines you have to get the raw
  content

Then you need to specify a regex option to match across line terminators i.e.[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12573413/6811411)

- `S`ingleLine mode (. matches any char including line feed), as well as
- `M`ultiline mode (^ and $ match embedded line terminators), e.g.
- (?smi) - note the "i" is to `i`gnore case
- the `?` to have an ungreedy match otherwise the start of one comment could match up the end of the last comment.

---

```
(Get-Content .\config.html -raw) -replace '(?smi)^\<!--.*?--\>?'
```

Checked this on [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/7lWHm3/1)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried this, it didn't work for me. It returns the file as it is. I do appreciate your detailed response @LotPings

Comment: Sorry, I pasted the wrong versiion from my tests, simply remove the `$` at the end of the RegEx. I'll edit the  answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't work for me. I tried taking off the $ from the end, but it still doesn't do anything.

Comment: What encoding does the file have? What PowerShell version do you use? I'm a bit clueless.

Comment: sorry for not providing the context. It's versionn 5 on Windows 10. 
This is a .config file basically a connectionstring which connects to the SQL. 
When I try to use this regex, it retireves the file as it is. Thanks for your help on this.