# Regex in Powershell fails to check for newlines

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm trying to get the first block of releasenotes...
*(See sample content in the code)*

Whenever I use something simple it works, 
 it only breaks when I try to 
search across multiple lines (`\n`). 
 I'm using `(Get-Content $changelog | Out-String)` because that gives back 1 string instead of an array from each line.

```
$changelog = 'C:\Source\VSTS\AcmeLab\AcmeLab Core\changelog.md'
$regex = '([Vv][0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\n)(^-.*$\n)+'

(Get-Content $changelog | Out-String) | Select-String -Pattern $regex -AllMatches

<#
SAMPLE:
------
v1.0.23
- Adds an IContainer API.
- Bugfixes.

v1.0.22
- Hotfix: Language operators.

v1.0.21
- Support duplicate query parameters.

v1.0.20
- Splitting up the ICommand interface.
- Fixing the referrer header empty field value.

#>
```

The result I need is:

```
v1.0.23
- Adds an IContainer API.
- Bugfixes.
```

**Update:**

Using [options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12572164/multiline-regex-to-match-config-block#12573413)..

```
$changelog = 'C:\Source\VSTS\AcmeLab\AcmeLab Core\changelog.md'
$regex = '(?smi)([Vv][0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\n)(^-.*$\n)+'

Get-Content -Path $changelog -Raw | Select-String -Pattern $regex -AllMatches
```

I also get nothing.. (no matter if I use `\n` or `\r\n`)

Comment: At the first glance it seems you may need to consider carriage returns before `\n` i.e `\r\n`

Comment: When I use '([Vv][0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\r\n)' as pattern the console returns the entire contents of the file? Even when I only use '([Vv][0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)'..?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- Unless you're stuck with PowerShell v2, it's simpler and more efficient to use `Get-Content -Raw` to read an entire file as a single string; besides, `Out-String` adds an extra newline to the string.<sup>[1]</sup>
- Since you're only looking for the *first* match, you can use the `-match` operator - no need for `Select-String`'s `-AllMatches` switch.

  - Note: While you could use `Select-String` without it, it is more efficient to use the `-match` operator, given that you've read the entire file into memory already.
- Regex matching is by default always case-*insensitive* in PowerShell, consistent with PowerShell's overall case-insensitivity.

Thus, the following returns the first block, if any:

```
if ((Get-Content -Raw $changelog) -match '(?m)^v\d+\.\d+\.\d+.*(\r?\n-\s?.*)+') { 
  # Match found - output it.
  $Matches[0] 
}
```

<sup>* `(?m)` turns on inline regex option `m` (multi-line), which causes anchors `^` and `$` to match the beginning and end of *individual lines* rather than the overall string's.</sup>

- `\r?\n` matches both CRLF and LF-only newlines.
- You could make the regex slightly more efficient by making the `(...)` subexpression *non-capturing*, given that you're not interested in what it captured: `(?:...)`.

Note that `-match` itself returns a *Boolean* (with a scalar LHS), but information about the match is recorded in the automatic `$Matches` hashtable variables, whose `0` entry contains the overall match.

---

As for **what you tried**:

```
'([Vv][0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\n)(^-.*$\n)+'
```

doesn't work, because by default `$` only matches at the very end of the input string, at the end of the *last* line (though possibly before a final newline).
To make `$` to match the end of *each line*, you'd have to turn on the multiline regex option (which you did in your 2nd attempt).
As a result, *nothing* matches.

```
'(?smi)([Vv][0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\n)(^-.*$\n)+'
```

doesn't work as intended, because by using option `s` (single-line) you've made `.` match *newlines too*, so that a greedy subexpression such as `.*` will match *the remainder of the string, across lines*.
As a result, everything from the first block on matches.

---

<sup>[1] This problematic behavior is discussed in [GitHub issue #14444](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14444).</sup>