# PowerShell not removing new line characters

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

**Environment**: Windows 10 pro 20H2, PowerShell 5.1.19041.1237

In a `.txt` file, my following `PowerShell` code is not replacing the newline character(s) with `" "`. **Question**: What I may be missing here, and how can we make it work?

**C:\MyFolder\Test.txt** File:

```
This is first line.
This is second line.
This is third line.
This is fourth line.
```

**Desired output** [after replacing the newline characters with " " character]:

```
This is first line. This is second line. This is third line. This is fourth line.
```

**PowerShell code**:

```
PS C:\MyFolder\test.txt> $content = get-content "Test.txt"
PS C:\MyFolder\test.txt> $content = $content.replace("`r`n", " ")
PS C:\MyFolder\test.txt> $content | out-file "Test.txt"
```

**Remarks**

The above code works fine if I replace some other character(s) in file. For example, if I change the second line of the above code with `$content = $content.replace("third", "3rd")`, the code successfully replaces `third` with `3rd` in the above file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiline regex to match config block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12572164/multiline-regex-to-match-config-block). [Classic PowerShell gotcha #8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69644807/1701026)

Comment: Note that out-file uses utf16 encoding by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass *`-Raw`* parameter to *[`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-5.1)*. By default, without the `Raw` parameter, content is [returned as an array of newline-delimited strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-5.1#example-6--get-raw-content).

```
Get-Content "Test.txt" -Raw
```

Quoting from the documentation,

> -**Raw**
>
> Ignores newline characters and returns the **entire contents of a file in one string with the newlines preserved**. By default, newline
> characters in a file are used as delimiters to separate the input into
> an array of strings. This parameter was introduced in PowerShell 3.0.

Comment: Your suggestion worked. Thank you for providing a reference - as it will help some other readers of this post, as well.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way of doing this is to **not** use the `-Raw` switch and then do a replacement on it, but make use of the fact that `Get-Content` splits the content on Newlines for you.

All it then takes is to join the array with a space character.

```
(Get-Content -Path "Test.txt") -join ' ' | Set-Content -Path "Test.txt"
```

---

As for what you have tried:

By using `Get-Content` **without** the `-Raw` switch, the cmdlet returns a string array of lines split on the Newlines.
That means there are **no** Newlines in the resulting strings anymore to replace and all that is needed is to 'stitch' the lines together with a space character.

If you **do** use the `-Raw` switch, the cmdlet returns a single, multiline string including the Newlines.
In your case, you then need to do the splitting or replacing yourself and for that, don't use the string method `.Replace`, but the regex operator `-split` or `-replace` with a search string `'\r?\n'`.

The question mark in there makes sure you split on newlines in Windows format (CRLF), but also works on *nix format (LF).

Comment: Thank you for sharing your thoughts. My upvote. You probably also meant to pipe the output back to the file. Based on your suggestion, following worked for me, as well:  `(Get-Content -Path "Test.txt") -join ' ' | Out-File "Test.txt"`

Comment: @nam Ah yes, saving to file using the pipe I didn't mention, but perhaps better use `Set-Content` for that as @js2010 [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69690420/powershell-not-removing-new-line-characters/69691546?noredirect=1#comment123185290_69690420)