# Need a similar command in powershell to "cat $CONFIG | sed -n '/start/,/^finish/p'"

Tags: powershell, sed, text-extraction

my first post and sorry for the rudimentary English. (asked bard for help)

I searched, I think for as long as four hours in a row, for how to do a similar command in PowerShell for the Linux shell command.

The goal is to catch any lines that are between two statements in a txt file that has an infinite number of lines.

found some function to do this, but works only with CHARACTERS, and i need to work with strings.
https://powershellone.wordpress.com/2021/02/24/using-powershell-and-regex-to-extract-text-between-delimiters/

please help

Comment: There is no difference between character and strings.  The issue is the return characters.  Regex has two modes : line and multi-line.  See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12572164/multiline-regex-to-match-config-block

Comment: As an aside, that's a [useless `cat`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat)

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Switch) statement with its `-File` and `-Regex` parameters:

```
& {
  $startOfRangeFound = $false
  switch -Regex -File $CONFIG {
    'start'   { $_; $startOfRangeFound = $true; continue }
    '^finish' { $_; break }
    default   { if ($startOfRangeFound) { $_ } }
  }
} # redirect to output file here or pipe to another command
```

Like your `sed` command (`cat $CONFIG | sed -n '/start/,/^finish/p'`), the above extracts a range of lines from the input file whose inclusive end points are defined by [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) patterns.

Specifically, it starts emitting lines from the input files once a line matching regex `start` is found, and stops emitting once a line matching `^finish` is found.

Note:

- The `& { ... }` enclosure (for *streaming* behavior) or an `$(...)` (for *collect-all-output-first* behavior) is only necessary if you
  need to use the above in a pipeline or redirect its output to a file
- To simply capture the results in a *variable* (which will receive an *array* of strings),<sup>[1]</sup> no enclosure is needed: you can use the `switch` call *as an expression*:

  ```
  $linesInRange = switch -Regex -File $CONFIG { ... }
  ```

---

<sup>[1] Strictly speaking, an array is only constructed if *two or more* lines are output. If you want to ensure that an array is assigned even if there's only *one* output line, use `$linesInRange = @(switch -Regex -File $CONFIG { ... })` or `[array] $linesInRange = switch -Regex -File $CONFIG { ... }`; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60020105/45375) for an explanation.</sup>