# How to represent a single object in a nested array as an array?

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell nested array with the below structure.

```
$jHosts = @(@("Host-1","Host-3"),@("Host-2","Host-4"),@("Host-5"))
```

As well as here is my powershell script to iterate the nested array.

```
    for($i=0; $i -le $jHosts.Length; $i++){  
        Write-Host $jHosts[$i]  
        for($k=0;$k -le $jHosts.Length; $k++){  
            Write-Output $jHosts[$i][$k]
        }
    }
```

The `Write-output` displays the output like below,

```
HOST-1
HOST-3
HOST-2
HOST-4
H
O
S
T
```

As my for loops reads all the values in first 2 nested arrays but it reads each character of a 3rd array's string when it is a single object. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pipe complete array-objects instead of array items one at a time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29973212/pipe-complete-array-objects-instead-of-array-items-one-at-a-time)

Comment: Have you accidentally set `$ErrorActionPreference ='SilentlyContinue'`? On my machine, Powershell shows several index errors if I run the above code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not able to reproduce your result, but your code contains two logical errors anyway:

1. You disregard the actual array boundaries by using the `-le` operator in your loop definitions. Use `-lt` instead.
2. You use the wrong length for your nested arrays. Replace `$jHosts.Length` by `$jHosts[$i].Length` in your "k" loop.

This is how your code seems to produce a valid result:

```
$jHosts = @(@("Host-1","Host-3"),@("Host-2","Host-4"),@("Host-5"))

for($i=0; $i -lt $jHosts.Length; $i++){  
    Write-Host $jHosts[$i]  
    for($k=0;$k -lt $jHosts[$i].Length; $k++){  
        Write-Output $jHosts[$i][$k]
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Host-1 Host-3
Host-1
Host-3
Host-2 Host-4
Host-2
Host-4
Host-5
Host-5
```

Answer (score 0):

To iterate through an array, use the `Count` property, rather than the `Length`.
In your case, because the last element in the array has only one item, it will be unwrapped by PowerShell to act as the single string "Host-5".

If you do `"Host-5".Length` the answer is `6` (6 characters in the string)
If you do `"Host-5".Count` the answer is `1` (just one single string)

Also, you are iterating one level too deep by doing `-le`, that should be `-lt` since you start iterating at 0.

```
$jHosts = @(@("Host-1","Host-3"),@("Host-2","Host-4"),@("Host-5"))
for($i=0; $i -lt $jHosts.Count; $i++){  
    for($k=0;$k -lt $jHosts[$i].Count; $k++){  
        Write-Output $jHosts[$i][$k]
    }
}
```

Returns

```
Host-1
Host-3
Host-2
Host-4
Host-5
```

If I add the extra line `Write-Host $jHosts[$i]` as in your code and do

```
$jHosts = @(@("Host-1","Host-3"),@("Host-2","Host-4"),@("Host-5"))
for($i=0; $i -lt $jHosts.Count; $i++){  
    Write-Host $jHosts[$i]
    for($k=0;$k -lt $jHosts[$i].Count; $k++){  
        Write-Output $jHosts[$i][$k]
    }
}
```

the result is

```
Host-1 Host-3
Host-1
Host-3
Host-2 Host-4
Host-2
Host-4
Host-5
Host-5
```