# PowerShell: Select-Object: Select half of files

Tags: powershell

Windows 10, version 10.0.19042.868

Hello,

I have PowerShell script for selecting first XXX files and moving into another folder.

```
Get-ChildItem -File *.txt | Sort-Object Name | Select-Object -First 25000 | Move-Item -Destination C:\txtFilesToProcess\
```

But how to select half of files from `Get-ChildItem`?

Comment: Get-ChildItem -File *.txt | Sort-Object Name | Select-Object -First (Get-ChildItem -File *.txt).Count/2 | Move-Item -Destination C:\txtFilesToProcess\

Comment: @VivekKumarSingh I'd avoid that, because you have double `Get-ChildItem`. Better use variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assign the output of `Get-ChildItem` to a variable so you know the number of files in advance.

This was the **accepted solution**:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -File *.txt | Sort-Object Name 
$files | Select-Object -First ($files.Count / 2) | Move-Item -Destination C:\txtFilesToProcess\
```

---

Alternative way using a **single pipeline** (more for academic purposes as it makes the code harder to understand):

```
,(Get-ChildItem -File *.txt) | ForEach-Object {
    $_ | Select-Object -First ($_.Count / 2) | Move-Item -Destination C:\txtFilesToProcess\ -WhatIf
}
```

- The parentheses (aka [grouping operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.1#grouping-operator--)) around the `Get-ChildItem` command collects all output of the command in an array, before proceeding with the next pipeline command.
- Additionally the [comma operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.1#comma-operator-) is required as a way to prevent enumeration of the array elements (see [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29973212/7571258) for details). It creates an array that contains the output array from `Get-ChildItem` as a single element.
- Now `ForEach-Object` operates on the whole `Get-ChildItem` output array, so we can use `$_.Count` to get the total number of files.