# How to exit from powershell function from function's statements

Tags: powershell

I expect that the return from the function statement (`begin`, `process`, `end`) should also terminate all its statements, but this does not happen.

I have a test function like this:

```
function test($a) {
    begin { 
        Write-Host 'begin ' -NoNewline
        if ($a -like '*begin*') { return; } 
    }
    process {
        Write-Host 'process ' -NoNewline
        if ($a -like '*process*') { return; } 
    }
    end {
        Write-Host 'end' -NoNewline
        if ($a -like '*end*') { return; } 
    }
}
```

And when I run it this way:

```
'begin', 'process', 'end' | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host "Try exit in $_ :`t" -NoNewline
    test $_
    Write-Host
}
```

Then I get a similar result:

```
Try exit in begin :     begin process end
Try exit in process :   begin process end
Try exit in end :       begin process end
```

But I would like the output from the function to also terminate its other statements and the output would be like this:

```
Try exit in begin :     begin
Try exit in process :   begin process
Try exit in end :       begin process end
```

How can I get it?

I tryed to use `break`, `continue` and `exit` instead of `return` but it terminated all script..

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_methods?view=powershell-7.1

Comment: Try to write code in a block to avoid this problem. https://stackoverflow.com/a/73411227/9631497

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your function is an [*advanced*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions_Advanced) function, and therefore uses `begin`, `process` and `end` blocks.

In a *simple* (non-advanced) function, in the *absence* of such blocks, `return` would indeed instantly exit the function, but from inside these blocks, `return` just exits *that block*.

(As an aside: `break` and `continue` only apply to *loop*-like constructs, and `exit` is meant to exit *scripts as a whole*, not individual functions).

---

If you want to exit your advanced function *as a whole* you have two basic choices:

- Throw an *error*, using a [`throw`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Throw) statement, which creates a *script*-terminating error (fatal by default).

  - To emulate the *statement*-terminating errors that *binary* cmdlets emit, you can use the [`$PSCmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.Cmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError) method (available to *advanced* functions such as yours) - by default, execution *resumes* in the caller's scope afterwards (after printing an error message).
  - If `throw` is used but *aborting execution overall* should be *prevented*, a caller must enclose the call in a [`try / catch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Try_Catch_Finally) statement (or, less commonly these days, use a [`trap`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Trap) statement).
- Use a custom `[bool]` variable that ignores attempts to (re)enter the `process` / the other blocks.

  - Note that in order to exit the per-pipeline-input-object `process` block *efficiently*, it would be helpful to be able to instruct upstream commands that no more input should be provided. However, this isn't an option as of PowerShell 7.4, but has been proposed as a future enhancement in [GitHub issue #3821](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3821).

---

To illustrate the technique of using a `[bool]` variable:

```
function test($a) {
  begin { 
    $done = $false
    Write-Host 'begin ' -NoNewline
    if ($a -like '*begin*') { $done = $true; return } 
  }
  process {
    if ($done) { return }
    Write-Host 'process ' -NoNewline
    if ($a -like '*process*') { $done = $true; return } 
  }
  end {
    if ($done) { return }
    Write-Host 'end' -NoNewline
    # Retained from your original code, but note that this is redundant: 
    # The function will exit here either way.
    if ($a -like '*end*') { return } 
  }
}
```

Comment: Understanding that an `Exit` will not exit the script is vital. A `throw` will exit the script.

Comment: @JariTurkia, `exit` does exit the _enclosing script_, not just the function at hand.

Comment: Ah, ok. When nesting scripts, things get tricky.

Comment: @JariTurkia, yes; if the intent is to _abort execution overall_, `throw` must be used (the resulting error can be caught by a caller, however).