# Return Multidimensional Array From Function

Tags: arrays, powershell, multidimensional-array

I encountered some issue in converting my existing vbs script to PowerShell script.  I have illustrate here with some dummy codes instead of my original code.  In example 1, I only have 1 set of elements in the array, upon return the array variable to the function, it will only display P.

However in example 2, where I have 2 set of elements in the array, upon return the array variable to the function, it will display the elements properly.

If you print the array inside the function in example 1 and 2. There isn't any issue in getting the results.

I have googled and not able to find any solution to it.  Many thanks in advance for the kind help.

**Example 1:**

```
function testArray {
    $array1 = @()
    $array1 += ,@("Apple","Banana")

    return $array1
}
$array2 = testArray
Write-Host $array2[0][1]
```

Result is "P".

**Example 2:**

```
function testArray {
    $array1 = @()
    $array1 += ,@("Apple","Banana")
    $array1 += ,@("Orange","Pineapple")

    return $array1
}
$array2 = testArray
Write-Host $array2[0][0]
```

Result is "Apple".

Comment: `return $array1` -> `return ,$array1` or `$array2 = testArray` -> `$array2 = @(testArray)`

Comment: @petseral it's works, any reason for that, or it's just syntax of powershell?

Comment: PowerShell unrolls arrays returned from a function. By prepending the returned array with the array construction operator (`,`) you wrap it in another array, which is unrolled on return, leaving the nested array intact.

Comment: Is this a duplicate question?  I'm sure this has to have been asked before on here.  Either way, it's my first time seeing this issue myself, and am grateful I came across it.  Kudos to you all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

PowerShell unrolls arrays returned from a function. Prepend the returned array with the [comma operator](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847732.aspx) (`,`, unary array construction operator) to wrap it in another array, which is unrolled on return, leaving the nested array intact.

```
function testArray {
    $array1 = @()
    $array1 += ,@("Apple","Banana")

    return ,$array1
}
```

Comment: What about `Write-Output -NoEnumerate $array1`?

Comment: What about it? Does it have any advantages over `return ,$array1` or just `,$array1`?

Comment: Presumably, the advantage is that it doesn't create an additional array. The disadvantage is it's too verbose and long to type.

Comment: I would consider the overhead of creating an array with a single nested array reference negligible.

Comment: @wOxxOm *Presumably, the advantage is that it doesn't create an additional array.* Not true. It create additional array as well.

Answer (score 1):

when you declare single line array like

```
$array1 = "Apple","Banana"
```

when you call :

```
$array1[0][1]
```

this will happen :

[image]

this code

```
function testArray {
    $array1 = @()
    $array1 += ,@("Apple","Banana")

    return $array1
}
$array2 = testArray
Write-Host $array2[0][1]
```

exact the same of this:

```
$array1 = "Apple","Banana"
```

but when you declare 2 row of array like :

```
function testArray {
    $array1 = @()
    $array1 += ,@("Apple","Banana")
    $array1 += ,@("Orange","Pineapple")

    return $array1
}
$array2 = testArray
Write-Host $array2[0][0]
```

this will happen :

[image]

if you need apple in your first code just call array[0] not array[0][0]. array[0][0] return char for you.

sorry for my bad english i hope you understand

Answer (score 0):

$array1 inside your function TestArray is always of rank 1, fixed, and has never an element with type array. Check how a + is defined on arrays.

In this case you want to use an ArrayList:
**$array1=[Collections.ArrayList]::new(10) # 10 is capacity**
After that you can use the **Add** function. Even with arrays. And this time they will not be flattened, as was the case with the + array operator.
Other dynamic collection types also exist. But this one looks ok for many purposes.