# Why does PowerShell flatten arrays automatically?

Tags: arrays, powershell, pipeline, jagged-arrays

I've written some pwsh code

```bsh
"a:b;c:d;e:f".Split(";") | ForEach-Object { $_.Split(":") }
# => @(a, b, c, d, e, f)
```

but I want this

```js
// in javascript
"a:b;c:d;e:f".split(";").map(str => str.split(":"))
[ [ 'a', 'b' ], [ 'c', 'd' ], [ 'e', 'f' ] ]
```

a nested array

```bsh
@(
    @(a, b),
    @(c, d),
    @(e, f),
)
```

Why? and what should I do

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the unary form of `,`, PowerShell's array-construction operator:

```
"a:b;c:d;e:f".Split(";") | ForEach-Object { , $_.Split(":") }
```

That way, the array returned by `$_.Split(":")` is effectively output as-is, as an *array*, instead of having its elements output *one by one*, which happens by default in a PowerShell pipeline.

`,` creates a - transient - *wrapper array* whose only element is the array you want to output. PowerShell then *unwraps* the wrapper array on output, passing the wrapped array through.

Answer (score 0):

With foreach-object, it's usually useful to unwrap the array:

```
ps | foreach modules | sort -u modulename
```

Answer (score 0):

You can alternatively create also a stack or a queue.
Below, I created with your array a stack.

```
$array = "a:b;c:d;e:f".Split(";")
$stack = New-Object -TypeName System.Collections.Stack
$array | ForEach-Object { $stack.Push($_.Split(":")) }
```

From here, the most used methods are `.Push()` to insert new items to your stack, `.Peek()` to use the first item of the stack and `.Pop()`, to retrieve and then remove the first item.

You mentioned that you wanted to create an array. This is also possible by using the `ToArray()` method.

```
$stackArray = $stack.ToArray()
$stackArray[2]
> a
> b
```

To keep in mind, creating a stack will inverse the order to the items.