# Returning a list of list , with only 1 list , it just returns a single list

Tags: powershell

The bellow example

```
Function Get-ListOfList
{

$listOfLists =  New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$List =  New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

$List.Add("A") | Out-Null
$List.Add("B") | Out-Null

$listOfLists.Add($List) | Out-Null  
return $listOfLists

}
```

I would  expect this to return a single list , with 1 item in it , a list.  That list has 2 strings in it.

But what is happening is that it returns a list , with 2 items in it.

```
  $l =  Get-ListOfList
  $l.Count
  $l.GetType().Name
  $l[0].Count
  $l[0].GetType().Name
  $l[1].Count
  $l[1].GetType().Name
```

outputs

```
2
ArrayList
1
String
1
String
```

This is messing  things up as the behavior is different  when the list of list has more then 1 item in it , it returns what you expect.

Comment: Yes this is expected, powershell is enumerating your output. use `, $listOfLists`

Comment: PowerShell [Gotcha `#4` the pipeline unrolls](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69644807/1701026)

Comment: So you are saying in PowerShell I can not expect to get back what is being returned , but I need an if statement , if I get a list of lists process it one way , and if I get a list of string process it another way.  Really ?

Comment: No, if you want to force an array output from within your function, you might use the [unary comma `,`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators#comma-operator-), see @Santiago's note, and if you want force an array at the outside of the function, you might use the [array subexpression operator `@( )`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators#array-subexpression-operator--), e.g.: `$l =  @(Get-ListOfList)`

Comment: Return the list of lists as 'return ,$ListOfList' with the comma prefix solves the problem.

Thanks