# how we can use vbs submatch() keyword in powershell script

Tags: powershell

I have a line in vbscript
Functioncall=x(0).Subdomain(0)
here functioncall is the name of a function
Now I need to rewrite this script into powershell..Do i need to write it like
Functioncall=$x.Item(0).Subdomain.Item(0)
(or)
Functioncall=$x.Item(0).Subdomain(0)

Comment: If you are returning a value from your function, you need to use
```return $x.Item(0).Subdomain.Item(0)```

Comment: If "*`Functioncall=x(0).Subdomain(0)` here functioncall is the name of a function*", I would expect the word `function` somewhere in your example. (please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)). Anyways, if you coming from another (scripting) language you might want to make yourself familiar with a few [pitfalls in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69644807/1701026). For your particular question: *1.* [parentheses and commas are not used with arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4988226/1701026). *2.* Indices are surrounded with square brackets, e.g.: `[0]`.