# PowerShell Method Invocation Failed error for Arraylist : Powershell 5.1

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.1

I have a powershell script which uses Arraylist and the same syntax works for some data and sometimes it throws error for different data.

```
$parsed_teamarrlist = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
```

After adding data `$parsed_teamarrlist` and writing to file , I try to clear the data in arraylist

```
if($parsed_teamarrlist) {
      $parsed_teamarrlist.Clear()
    }
```

During execution, for some data, it does not throws error, where as sometimes it throws the below error for different data.

```
Method invocation failed because [System.String] does not contain a method named 'Clear'.
+           $parsed_teamarrlist.Clear()
+           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

Comment: only possible way this could happen would be if you reassigned a string to that variable or the variable was previously coerced to be a string. you need to add more code to get a better understanding of what is wrong with it

Comment: With the limitted info available, I guess it concernes a classic PowerShell issue where [4a.. PowerShell unrolls single item collections](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69644807/1701026)

Comment: You may have only one item in the list and often PS will convert to a singleton.  Adding @() around the object will force to an array : @($parsed_teamarrlist).Clear()

Comment: @iRon - Your solution works, at times there is single value in the arraylist . I had to convert it to Array and clear it. It worked. Can you please write as solution, so that I can accept the answer