# New-DlpComplianceRule: parameter 'AdvancedRule'. Cannot convert value to type System.String

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell, azure-security

I am trying to follow MS article,
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/new-dlpcompliancerule?view=exchange-ps

**Example 3**

```
$data = Get-Content -Path "C:\Data\Sensitive Type.txt" -ReadCount 0
New-DLPComplianceRule -Name "Contoso Rule 1" -Policy "Contoso Policy 1" -AdvancedRule $data -NotifyUer
```

But getting an error saying that $data is not string.
My colleagues PC works fine but mine requires out-string in the first line.
What is the difference?
Any advice is appreciated.

Thank you,

Comment: This is a common misunderstanding, [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) doesn't indeed return a (single) string but an array of strings (`string[]`) for each line. Try: `Get-Content -Raw` or `$Data | Foreach-Object { Do-YourThingWith $_ }`. See also [PowerShell gotcha `#8`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69644807/1701026)

Comment: Yes, the out put type is an array, that's what I figure too. but then this sample command from MS is not right? or they assume using certain version.. Thank you,

Comment: Related: [`#4242` Consistently document a scalar -InputObject parameter as an implementation detail or make item-by-item processing cmdlets explicitly iterate over collections](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4242)

Comment: So it's depends on the version of Powershell? I don't really get it yet.

Comment: I don't believe it is a PowerShell version issue (please add both versions to the question). If look to the [`-advancedrule` parameter for the `new-dlpcompliancerule` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/exchange/new-dlpcompliancerule?view=exchange-ps#-advancedrule), you will see that the input `Type` is `String` and if you check ($Data.GetType()`) you will see that this is: `String[]` (a String *Array*). Confirm these types on both your and your colleagues PC. Btw. It could also be a module (`get-Command New-DlpComplianceRule`) version difference.

Answer (score 2):

> I agree with @iRon, `Get-Content` cmdlet returns an **array of strings** for each line.
>
> But  `-AdvancedRule` parameter of the **New-DLPComplianceRule**
> cmdlet expects a single string as input.

When I ran the same code in my environment, I got **same error** saying `Connot convert value to type System.String`:

```
Connect-IPPSSession
$data = Get-Content -Path "C:\Data\Sensitive Type.txt" -ReadCount 0
New-DLPComplianceRule -Name "Contoso Rule 1" -Policy "Contoso Policy 1" -AdvancedRule $data -NotifyUer
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **resolve** the error, you need to add `Out-String`  at the end that converts the array of strings returned by the **Get-Content** cmdlet to a single string.

When I added `Out-String`  at the end, I got the response successfully like below:

```
$data = Get-Content -Path "C:\Data\Sensitive Type.txt" -ReadCount 0 | Out-String
New-DLPComplianceRule -Name "Contoso Rule 1" -Policy "Contoso Policy 1" -AdvancedRule $data -NotifyUser user@xxxxxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com
```

**Response:**

[image]

To confirm that, I checked the same in **Microsoft Purview** Portal where Data loss prevention compliance rule named `Contoso Rule 1` created successfully:

[image]

If it's working in your colleagues PC without adding `Out-String`, verify whether you are using **different version** of PowerShell compared to them by running below command:

```
$PSVersionTable.PSVersion
```

[image]

Comment: I will ask the colleague running that command and see what's the difference.. Thank you,

Comment: Mine is 5.1.19041.3031, Colleague's one is 5.1.19041.2673. Just a revision difference.....