# Why does putting the mass search and replace command in function make it not working?

Tags: powershell, function, replace

In `test.txt` I have:

```
hi
```

In `test.ps1` I have:

```
function searchAndReplace {
    param (
        $search, $replace
    )
        
    $search
    $replace
    Get-ChildItem *.txt -recurse -File | ForEach-Object { 
        (Get-Content $_).Replace($search, $replace) | Set-Content $_ 
    } 
}
$value1 = 'hi'
$value2 = 'hello'
searchAndReplace($value1, $value2)
```

Running the script doesn't change the string. However using the command directly in the shell works:

```
Get-ChildItem -recurse -File |  ForEach-Object { (Get-Content $_).Replace('hi', 'hello') | Set-Content $_ }
```

Do you know why is that?

Comment: `searchAndReplace $value1 $value2` or `searchAndReplace -search $value1 -replace $value2`. see linked question

Comment: See also [PowerShell Pitfalls](https://stackoverflow.com/q/803521/1701026)