# Powershell 2d array foreach loop

Tags: powershell, multidimensional-array, foreach

Currently I have a for each in a function. When I call it in 2 different scenarios is wierd.

If the 2d array has multiple and ask for the first slot of each then it outputs correctly.

for example:

```
$packManagers = @( # (Name, executable, Path)
    @("PowerShell Core", "pwsh", "Microsoft.Powershell"),
    @("Git", "git", "Git.Git"),
    @("NVM", "nvm", "CoreyButler.NVMforWindows"),
    @("Python", "py", "Python3")
```

Output

```
- Powershell Core
- Git
- NVM
- Python
```

but when I outputed only one value then it start going through all the items inside the only one and getting the first character.
For example:

```
$packScoop = @( # (Name, executable, Path)
    @("Scoop", "scoop", "get.scoop.sh")
)
```

Output

```
- S
- s
- g
```

I as well tried with the following to do some testing and the output was different than expected.

code:

```
foreach ($curr in @(@("HI", "Bi", "Try"))) {
    Write-Host "$($curr[0]) - $($curr[1]) - $($curr[2])"
}
```

Expected:

```
HI - Bi - Try
```

Actual:

```
H - I - 
B - i -
T - r - y
```

Comment: What is a `$curr`?

Comment: You hit one of the most [common gothas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69644807/1701026) of PowerShell

Answer (score 0):

Collections of collections created with a single item are often squished(others will most likely going to explain you why)

If you are MAKING a single-item array: instead of `@(@(<#content#>))` use `,@(<#content#>)`

```
foreach ($curr in ,@("HI", "Bi", "Try")) {
    Write-Host "$($curr[0]) - $($curr[1]) - $($curr[2])"
}
```

though I suggest to get used into using `List` instead of arrays as they resolve a lot of issues.

Comment: $curr is the variable that contains the values inside of the array. I dont want 1d but a 2d. there is a function I have that takes in arrays and does something with the 3 columns inside of it. But if I have one it does not take the group of 3 but actually takes the values inside the double array. I want just to return the 1d array of the 2d array

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to fix it. So powershell with arrays when there is only one present element in an array then it interpets it implicitly as non nested arrays.

For Example:

```
$arr1 = @("Hi", "Bye")
Write-Host $arr1

$arr2 = @("Hi")
Write-Host $arr2
```

Output:

```
Object[] -> Array type
String
```

To fix this you need to add a comma in the beggining

Example:

```
$arr2 = @(,"Hi")
Write-Host $arr2
```

Output:

```
Object[] -> Type Array
```

Comment: That's only needed if the object isn't already explicitly set to be an array. `[array]$arr2 = @("Hi")` will always be an array even when you only provide it with one item. Have a look at Casting, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/lang-spec/chapter-07?view=powershell-5.1#729-cast-operator