Obtaining Windows Updates information
I'm trying to gather some detailed information about each of my machines on the network. I'd like to extract the Windows Updates information and see if they are out by a maximum of 30 days, and this is what I've managed to piece together. I know that they work individually, but not when I put them together.
Hopefully someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong on with it;
$WUpdateResult = (Get-Hotfix | Sort-Object -Property InstalledOn -Descending | Select-Object -First 1).InstalledOn
$WUR30Days = $WUpdateResult -lt 30
$info.WUpdateResult = if ($WUR30Days = "False") { $WUpdateResult } else { "N/A" }


There are a couple of potential issues here:
Comparison to today's date
The InstalledOn property gives you a date when the update was installed, but you are not comparing this with today's date. Perhaps this is what you want:
((Get-Date) - $WUpdateResult).Days -lt 30

If expression
Additionally $WUR30Days = "False" just assigns the value "False" to the variable WUR30Days - try this instead:
$WUR30Days -eq $false

or, even simpler, try:
-not $WUR30Days

Example of assignment operator (=) instead of (-eq) in if expression
This snippet shows how the single equals sign is confusing when used in if expressions:
$ThisIsDefinitelyFalse = $(get-date).Day -gt 100

Write-Host $ThisIsDefinitelyFalse
Write-Host $ThisIsDefinitelyFalse.GetType()

if ($ThisIsDefinitelyFalse = "False") {
    Write-Host "WTF?!"
}
if ($ThisIsDefinitelyFalse = "True") {
    Write-Host "WTF?!?!"
}

Write-Host $ThisIsDefinitelyFalse
Write-Host $ThisIsDefinitelyFalse.GetType()

The output is:
False
System.Boolean
WTF?!
WTF?!?!
True
System.String

The expressions inside the if statements return what is being passed through (either "True" or "False") - both of which are converted to $true when subject to Boolean evaluation (try: if ("False") { write-host "?"}). You can also see that the variable used to be a Boolean, and has now changed to a string. This expression inside the if updated the value of the variable:
$ThisIsDefinitelyFalse = "True"


Further resources for common Powershell issues: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/803521/powershell-pitfalls/69644807#69644807
